# How to merge new elements into a List in Gosu

Tags: gosu

E.g. I have a List of objects, List A, and its initialized with 7 elements. Each element is ordered by an integer field called "elementOrder".

How can I take a new List of the same objects, List B, and merge them into List A based on the "elementOrder"?

Note that List B contains duplicates of List A and I only want to merge unique elements of List B into List A.

Thanks you.
S

Comment: Figured this out; just do a firstWhere() on the List A to find the element at which you want to merge in a new element, then use the index of this element to add the new element. This pushes the existing element up to the next index.

Answer (score 0):

```
//copy ListA element on a new list 
var newList = new ArrayList<ElementType>(ListA)
//add B elements to new list 
newList.addAll(ListB)
//order the new list with elementOrder column
newList = newList.orderBy( \ element -> element.elementOrder)
```

Q : List B contains duplicates of List A and I only want to merge unique elements of List B into List A

R : you must use Blocks (lambda expressions) to filter duplicates elements

```
//copy ListA element on a new list 
var newList = new ArrayList<ElementType>(ListA)
//filter B elements not in ListA
var FiltredListB = ListB.where( \ element -> not ListA.contains(element))
//add FiltredListB elements to new list 
newList.addAll(FiltredListB)
//order the new list with elementOrder column
newList = newList.orderBy( \ element -> element.elementOrder)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse but I actually missed an important point in the question, I edited it to reflect this. Note that List B contains duplicates of List A and I only want to merge unique elements of List B into List A.